# How do I compare a string to multiple, but separate, arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to write a script that I can implement into WordPress. The purpose of this doesn't really matter.

What I am trying to get is the script to detect the URL, see if any part of the URL contains a string from one of 4 different arrays, and then include the correct file.

This is what I currently have:

```
<?php
    //Detect URL and remove slashes and ".php"
    $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $find = array( '/', '.php');
    $clear = array( ' ', ' ');

    //Arrays to detect from
    $region1 = array( 'LosAngeles', 'SantaMonica', 'Hollywood' );
    $region2 = array( 'Houston', 'Dallas' );
    $region3 = array( 'Las Vegas', 'SaltLakeCity' );

    //Assign a region
    if ( in_array( $url, $region1 ) ) {
            $region = "California";
        }
        elseif ( in_array( $url, $region2 ) ) {
            $region = "Texas";
        }
        elseif ( in_array( $url, $region3 ) ) {
            $region = "Nevada";
        }

    //Load file based on region
    if ( $region = "California"; ) {
            include "file1.php";
        }
        elseif ( $region = "Texas" ) {
            include "file2.php";
        }
        elseif ( $region = "Nevada" ) {
            include "file3.php";
        }
?>
```

I have already tried `foreach`, but that doesn't let you run a loop for more than 1 array. I am also not trying to do an `array_intersect`. Just checking that the URL matches at least one of the arrays.

All your guys' help is appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Are you going to describe what isn't working with your code?

Comment: Difficult to answer with incomplete code but I'd suggest a multidimensional array and a nested for each loop

Answer (score 1):

You already name `foreach` and `array` in your question and that points into the right direction.

But first I'd like to point out this variable naming:

```
//Arrays to detect from
$region1 = array( ... );
$region2 = array( ... );
$region3 = array( ... );
```

These three variable actually can be easier represented by an array which again makes that variable then compatible with `foreach` as you can use it to iterate (traverse over) an array:

```
$regions = [
   "California" => [ ... ],
   "Texas" => [ ... ],
   "Nevada" => [ ... ],
];

foreach ($regions as $region => $cities) {
    ...
}
```

Now what you only need is a map from regions to file-names to include:

```
$files = [
    "California" => "file1",
    "Texas" => "file2",
    ...
]
```

Then you can map it within the `foreach` easily:

```
if (!isset($files[$region])) {
   throw new UnexpectedValueException(sprintf("File for region %s missing", var_export($region, true))));
}
$file = sprintf("%s.php", $files[$region]);
include($file);
return;
```

This mini-program will check if there is a file defined for a region and then include it. It's different to your example as it does not use an if clause but just returns if there is a region match. Even though, a matching reason is even expected in the first place.

So you need to wire this within the loop to find that one case that matches the region based on cities:

```
foreach ($regions as $region => $cities) {
    if (!in_array($url, $cities)) 
        continue;
    }
    if (!isset($files[$region])) {
        throw new UnexpectedValueException(
            sprintf("File for region %s missing", var_export($region, true)));
    }
    $file = sprintf("%s.php", $files[$region]);
    include($file);
    return;
}
throw new UnexpectedValueException(
    sprintf("No region found for URL %s", var_export($url, true))
);
```

Take-aways:

- Do not number variables -> nearly always this is a sign you can take an array instead.
- If there is one case out of many it's often a single if within a loop.
- Arrays in PHP are also a hash-map. You can ask if something exists (e.g. by it's key). Use maps to your benefit.